# Build Errror "spawn spctl ENOENT" on MAC OS X Slave that runs with Jenkins

Tags: node.js, macos, jenkins, electron, jenkins-agent

We settled up our Jenkins-server with a mac slave, that runs on my local developer machine. It has been made to create application apps by electron/node.js.

Jenkins connects to my os x machine via ssh and my username/password. I can see that during the build our app-directory is made and saved on my machine at the specified location. (slave.jar, workspace-directory, and so on).

The Jenkins now runs into an error as follows if the code signing starts:

```
[mac] [ExampleApp] Running shell script

[mac] + npm run dist-mac
[mac] 
[mac] > ExampleApp@1.3.3-beta dist-mac ../workspace/Example-App/ExampleApp
[mac] > build -m
[mac] 

[mac] Warning: "directories" in the root is deprecated, please specify in the "build"

[mac] Rebuilding native production dependencies for darwin:x64

[mac] Packaging for darwin x64 using electron 1.4.13 to ../ExampleApp-dist/mac

[mac] Signing app (identity: Developer ID Application: Example Company Name (ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ))
[mac] 

[mac] Error: spawn spctl ENOENT
[mac]     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1023:11)
[mac]     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
[mac]     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
[mac]     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
[mac]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
[mac] From previous event:
[mac]     at MacPackager.sign (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-builder/out/macPackager.js:253:11)
[mac]     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-builder/src/macPackager.ts:81:26
[mac] From previous event:
[mac]     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-builder/src/macPackager.ts:81:10
[mac]     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
[mac] From previous event:
[mac]     at MacPackager.pack (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-builder/out/macPackager.js:173:11)
[mac]     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-builder/src/packager.ts:210:22
[mac] From previous event:
[mac]     at Packager.doBuild (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-builder/out/packager.js:335:11)
[mac]     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-builder/src/packager.ts:151:38
[mac]     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
[mac]     at runCallback (timers.js:651:20)
[mac]     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:624:5)
[mac]     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:596:5)
[mac] From previous event:
[mac]     at Packager.build (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-builder/out/packager.js:261:11)
[mac]     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-builder/src/builder.ts:214:40
[mac]     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
[mac] From previous event:
[mac]     at build (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-builder/out/builder.js:63:21)
[mac]     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-builder/out/cli/build-cli.js:68:41)
[mac]     at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
[mac]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
[mac]     at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
[mac]     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
[mac]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
[mac]     at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
[mac]     at run (bootstrap_node.js:418:7)
[mac]     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
[mac]     at bootstrap_node.js:533:3
[mac] 
[mac] npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
[mac] npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dist-mac"
[mac] npm ERR! node v7.5.0
[mac] npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
[mac] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[mac] npm ERR! ExampleApp@1.3.3-beta dist-mac: `build -m`
[mac] npm ERR! Exit status 255
[mac] npm ERR! 
[mac] npm ERR! Failed at the ExampleApp@1.3.3-beta dist-mac script 'build -m'.
[mac] npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
[mac] npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ExampleApp package,
[mac] npm ERR! not with npm itself.
[mac] npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
[mac] npm ERR!     build -m
[mac] npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
[mac] npm ERR!     npm bugs ExampleApp
[mac] npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
[mac] npm ERR!     npm owner ls ExampleApp
[mac] npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
[mac] 
[mac] npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
[mac] npm ERR!     ../workspace/Example-App/ExampleApp/npm-debug.log
```

The funny part of it is, that if I connect manually by ssh from another machine to my local-machine an execute the "build -m"-function by terminal, then the build runs perfect and without errors.

What do I need to set in the preferences that it works also with Jenkins-SSH? Or why do I get his error only from Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's an ideal solution for our problem, but it's at least a workaround.

As we suggested, the problem is in the missing environment-variables, if we start from jenkins-ssh. Thus we made a script, that starts the build-process manually and  set all environment-variables that we could get by command 'printenv' if we are in terminal of the mac - where the build process runs without errors.

Thus my called script looks for example as follows:

```
#! /bin/sh
################################################################################
# starts build manually and sets environment variables manually before starting build
################################################################################
# first get environment-values with command "printenv" in terminal on the desired system, where build process runs 
# then set all line outputs with starting "export "; some example lines as follows
export SHELL=/bin/bash
export TERM=xterm-256color
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx3g -XX:PermSize=1024m
export PATH=/opt/subversion/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home
export CLASSPATH_SEP=:
export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
export XPC_FLAGS=0x0
export XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
export LESSCHARSET=latin1
export SHLVL=1
export HOME=/Users/exampleUser
export GIT_HOME=/usr/bin/
export TMP=/tmp
export LOGNAME=exampleUser
export CLASSPATH=
export GIT_SRC_HOME=/Users/exampleUser/git
export SECURITYSESSIONID=186a9
export _=/usr/bin/printenv

# now starts build
cd <path-To-App-Directory>
build -m

# if desired check if app is signed
#spctl --assess -vv "<path-to-build-application>"
#codesign --verify -vvvv "<path-to-build-application>"
```

We don't know which lines are necessary but as long as the script runs, everything is fine for us.

Maybe some other specialist might know the professional solution to our problem. Up to this time we mark this solution as the correct answer.